# Extract link from mouseover hover element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape from a mouseover hoverable element in [python](/questions/tagged/python) [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium). However, I get the error NameError: name 'campaign_link' is not defined. I am getting the feeling that I do not select the right element, but I have tried several and still can't click on the link element inside the hover element. This is my code:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

# Specify driver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 2)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.get('https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/flash-pro-world-s-fastest-powerbank-redesigned#/')

campaign_info = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".basicsCampaignOwner-details-name > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)")
campaign_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tooltipHover-hoverContent-body > div:nth-child(1)")))
campaign_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".tooltipHover-hoverContent-body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(4)"))

actions=ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(campaign_info).move_to_element(campaign_box).move_to_element(campaign_link).click().perform()
```

It should go to the campaign owner webpage, but it stays on the campaign webpage. What am I doing wrong here? Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong, unreliable locators.
Also, you should wait for element visibility, not just to element presence.
And the main issue - the `campaign_box` and `campaign_link` elements are not clickable and even not existing until you hover over the `campaign_info` element.
So you have to wait for `campaign_info` visibility. Then hover over it and then go to `campaign_link` and click it!
Try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

# Specify driver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 2)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.get('https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/flash-pro-world-s-fastest-powerbank-redesigned#/')

campaign_info = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.desktop.campaignOwnerName-tooltip.t-body--sansSerif--lg")))
actions=ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(campaign_info).perform()
campaign_link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[class='campaignOwnerDetail-pastCampaigns t-body--sansSerif']"))
actions.move_to_element(campaign_link).click().perform()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do indeed see the hover campaign_info element appear (which I did not see before). However, it still does not recognize the campaign_link element. I need to go to the link of the campaign owner "view full profile". I get the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'campaign_link' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, forgot converting `"` to `'`. Please try it now. It should work

Comment: Thank you! I found another minor mistake. The campaign_link element missed a pair of brackets. This is the correct code `campaign_link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[class="campaignOwnerDetail-pastCampaigns t-body--sansSerif"]')))`. Thank you so much for your help, you're a life saver!!!!